# Haskell Error - Couldn't match expected type

Tags: function, haskell, types

i want to write a function for building a list of random numbers
and here comes the code ive written

```
buildlist :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
buildlist n m = do
    seed <- getStdGen
    let l = randomRs (0, m) seed
    let list = take n l
    return list
```

and then the errors

```
    Couldn't match expected type `[t0]' with actual type `IO StdGen'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: seed <- getStdGen
In the expression:
  do { seed <- getStdGen;
       let l = randomRs ... seed;
       let list = take n l;
       return list }
In an equation for `buildlist':
    buildlist n m
      = do { seed <- getStdGen;
             let l = ...;
             let list = ...;
             .... }
```

ps.haskell is so different from c,java,ruby that i feel i've nerver learnt coding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are using IO (`getStdGen`), the whole function must be in `IO` monad. Change the return type to

```
buildList :: Int -> Int -> IO [Int]
```

and *do* read a good book :-)

Comment: thanks a lot.it's hard to buy a book about haskell in china. and english website is hard to understand. T_T

Comment: There are two excellent books that you can read online: http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/ and http://learnyouahaskell.com/. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any materials in Chinese, but if you speak any other languages, check  http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Books and http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tutorials. Translations of tutorials in other languages do appear from time to time, so keep checking those sites. And perhaps you'll translate one of the tutorials into your language!